# How to restrict the permissions of a google drive API key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I have a Google Cloud API Key (shown below) which is restricted to only use the Google Drive API. I want to restrict which methods in the API this key can use.

[image: drive]

I know that Google can distinguish use of each method because they allow you to view the usage of individual methods in the "Metrics" tab (shown below). Since there's a way to view usage of each individual method, there is likely also a way to limit usage of a particular method to zero. I am confident that there's a way to do this within Google Cloud but I am not an experienced Google Cloud user so I'm probably looking in the wrong places. Any form of solution, even a workaround or "hack" would be greatly helpful.

[image: api]

Comment: You cannot restrict the API methods, only the services. An API Key does not provide any authorization information. Edit your post and explain how you are using the API Key and what data are you accessing. In some cases there are much better methods, one is OAuth where you can implement fine-grained authorization and is preferred over API Keys.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how OAuth would help with this? My goal is to have a permission given to anonymous users that allows them to upload files using the "upload" method but not allow them to use any of the other methods because then they would be able to delete files.

Comment: Google has good documentation on Google Drive OAuth. I would never allow anonymous users to upload files. I will post an answer to your original question. My advice is to rethink what you are implementing. If you have more questions, create a new StackOverflow post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot restrict the API methods that an API Key supports, only the services it can call. An API Key does not provide any authorization information.